# WhatsApp PHP API: Getting encrypted message

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am using WhatsApp [Library](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/) for communicating with WhatApp. I have written code to get messages but it's returning as:

```
3(�����Ƈ0��!:�΃�j���d��$���9�*�0o��=z!���Nx>yPLWEN�DN�X���m�D��\�=
u"P3
!�2��(Y�G�}ثzXr<����"-�<�vRi�o" �,�F��׫��u~��{�>�uR�Wy��r�ɾF��PV�iK"
```

My code is below:

```
echo "<br>Getting message<br>";
$w->pollMessage();
$msgs = $w->GetMessages();
foreach ($msgs as $m) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

Comment: I assume you read the github repository and added the libraries it's mentioning? `Requires: PHP Protobuf and Curve25519 to enable end to end encryption`

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes I even installed both but on other hand I have only `.proto` files there. Do I need to generate classes from them? If yes the how to do and how to integrate here?

Comment: I simply took a guess that it was something like that missing - a shame to hear that it's not. Have you tried running their [full example](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/blob/master/tests/whatsapp.php) in a cli prompt to see whether their own example even works?

Comment: @h2ooooooo it's rather printing html on console

Comment: What kind of HTML? From what I can see in the source code there's no HTML being output in the cli app

Comment: I am talking about `whatsapp.php`

Comment: Yes, but `whatsapp.php` has absolutely no HTML in it so if you're getting HTMl out then you're doing it wrong. Take a in the actual file: https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/blob/master/tests/whatsapp.php It prints absolutely no HTML. You need to run this in a command line interface (CLI) - NOT through your browser.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Check this: http://imgur.com/NZ9vBqV  - Seems redirecting to WhatsApp

Comment: That does indeed seem to be HTML - most likely it's redirecting to the login prompt (Whatsapp Login). I'd save the HTML it's printing out to an actual HTML file and see what it contains. There might be an error in there. Did you read this BTW? Don't know if it's relevant: https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsApp-Registration-Flow